# Kotlin mutablestateof error when holding state of string

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to convert an enum to a list of strings to be used in a dropdown menu to then be selected and saved.

The Enum and method for converting...

```
enum class ExerciseType(val exercise: String) {
    CHEST("Chest"),
    LEG("Leg"),
    ARMS("Arms"),
    CORE("Core"),
    LOWER_BODY("Lower Body"),
    UPPER_BODY("Upper Body")
}

fun getExerciseTypesAsStrings() : List<String> {
    return ExerciseType.values().map {it.exercise}
}
```

Here is where I get the converted enums, converted an array, to be used in the muteableStateOf function. This is where the problem is. It doesn't like this for some reason and is asking
"Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate"

```
val exerciseTypeValues = getExerciseTypesAsStrings().toTypedArray() // enum converted to array<string>
var exerciseType by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf( exerciseTypeValues[0])}
```

The line "var exerciseType by rememberSaveable..." is the one that is causing the problem.

And I plan on using this value in this composable function

```
@Composable
fun ExerciseTypeInput(
    values: ArrayList<String>,
    modifier: Modifier,
    updateExerciseType: (String) -> Unit
) {
    ButtonSpinner(
        items = values,
        modifier = modifier,
        itemClick = {
            updateExerciseType(it)
        }
    )
}
```

Where there will be a drop down and then the value can be selected (updating the exercise type chosen) to be used for persistence.

Not really sure where I'm going wrong as I'm following a guide that has written this almost verbatim, except for the fact they get their array of strings from an ArrayStringResource in their res folder like this:

```
var values = stringArrayResource(R.array.gender_array)
val genderValues = values.copyOfRange(1, values.size)
var gender by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf( genderValues[0] ) }
```

I hope you can see how these two implementations are similar (in that they get an array of strings, and then use a muteablestate to remember a position in that array).
However this second example works and I can't see why.

If I add the  "getValue" and "setValue" methods the error requests me to add, my app produces this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I cannot see your Enum class nor your `getExerciseTypesAsStrings` method. I've made a quick code to get enum names and custom variables - https://pl.kotl.in/fK3KDGQEG. You can then use these in your dropdown. Not sure if it's what you are looking for. Please be more specific or provide more of your code. Also, there is a small error `mutableStateOf(exerciseTypeValues[0)` -> `mutableStateOf(exerciseTypeValues[0])`

Comment: I have edited for clarity. Hopefully it is more understandable what my problem is now. I do not understand this to be a fault of the Enum, however I have changed my enum to fit what you showed, and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I think its an issue with using the "by" keyword. As even when I replace the `mutableStateOf( exerciseTypeValues[0])` with `mutableStateOf( "" ) ` I get the same error. Am I misunderstanding how these are used?

Comment: Do you have `import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue` and `import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue` imported? Or instead use `=` for the `by`.

Comment: when using those, I got the output shown in the attached image. Which isn't what I want

Comment: can you include part where you pass this value into Exposed DropDown

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty correct as per the code you posted, still I'm attaching the entire code for your reference.

Hope it helps!

```
package com.example.composeplayground
    
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuBox
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.example.composeplayground.ui.theme.ComposePlaygroundTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposePlaygroundTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    ExerciseDropdownMenu()
                }
            }
        }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ExerciseDropdownMenu() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val exerciseTypeValues = getExerciseTypesAsStrings().toTypedArray() // enum converted to array<string>
    var exerciseType by remember { mutableStateOf(exerciseTypeValues[0]) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = expanded.not() }
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = exerciseType,
            onValueChange = {},
            readOnly = true,
            label = { Text("Select an option") },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
        ) {
            exerciseTypeValues.forEach { item ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = item) },
                    onClick = {
                        exerciseType = item
                        expanded = false
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
}


enum class ExerciseType(val exercise: String) {
    CHEST("Chest"),
    LEG("Leg"),
    ARMS("Arms"),
    CORE("Core"),
    LOWER_BODY("Lower Body"),
    UPPER_BODY("Upper Body")
}

fun getExerciseTypesAsStrings() : List<String> {
    return ExerciseType.entries.map {it.exercise}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to work with a `TypedArray`.

```
// avoid toTypedArray
val exerciseTypeValues = getExerciseTypesAsStrings()

// use .first() for accessing the first element
var exerciseType by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf( exerciseTypeValues.first())}
```